# Is there any significance to the lemons and the port in Ko Un's "Asking the Way"?

Tags: poetry, wording-choice, korean-language, ko-un

["Asking the Way"](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poetrymagazine/poems/57527/asking-the-way) is a short poem by Ko Un, addressing "You fools who ask what god is" and telling them to ask about life instead, illustrating the principle with examples about lemon trees and drinkers in a port. The main point of the poem is clear, but I wonder if there's any significance to the specific examples chosen to illustrate it? **Why lemon trees and drinkers, in particular, rather than anything else?** E.g. would these words have some significance wordplay-wise in the original Korean, or do lemons symbolise something in Korean culture, or anything like that?